# Start MongoDB With Authentication Enabled

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

Well I am new in MongoDB. Just started using 2 tutorials from tutorialspoint and w3resource. I am really enjoying learning it. I think it is really the future of database management. However I have faced some problems and I want to clear my conceptions on those issues. Here is the first question of the stack of noted questions. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32bit machine and O/S). My MongoDB version is 2.6.11. I use terminal to toy with MongoDB. According to MongoDB website I start the server `mongod` using this command...

```
$sudo service mongod start
```

Now to start the server with authentication enabled what should be the command? I tried using

`$sudo service mongod --auth start`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? It doesn't start? It starts without authentication? We need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue described in above mentioned post I suggest you to check  authentication options into mongodb configuration file.

```
# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
auth = true
```

**And after it initialize mongod service using auth mode.**

```
sudo mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Auth configuration option should be set to true and accordingly mongo service will start in authentication mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description i can understand that you installed mongoDB using rpm package, for this you can find the cnf file in /etc/mongod.conf 
open this file as root user

```
vi /etc/mongod.cnf
```

un comment the auth line

```
auth = true
```

save and exit, now you can start the service as

```
sudo service mongod start
```

but before enabling the auth make sure you have one **admin user** who has all the roles to perform the administration works